# How to disable dropdown on hover (wordpress)?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dropdown

The following code shows 2 dropdowns on hover.
I need to disable dropdown.
I tried the following code but it still dorps down.
No error in console.
Would you please let me know how to disable dropdown?
Existing code created using a plugin:

```
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-d9e3cb4 elementor-widget__width-initial elementor-widget elementor-widget-shortcode" data-id="d9e3cb4" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="shortcode.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                <div class="elementor-shortcode">
<div class="wpml-ls-statics-shortcode_actions wpml-ls wpml-ls-legacy-dropdown js-wpml-ls-legacy-dropdown" disabled="true">
    <ul>

        <li tabindex="0" class="wpml-ls-slot-shortcode_actions wpml-ls-item wpml-ls-item-ko wpml-ls-current-language wpml-ls-first-item wpml-ls-item-legacy-dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="js-wpml-ls-item-toggle wpml-ls-item-toggle">
            <img class="wpml-ls-flag" src="https://www.myweb.com/wp-content/uploads/flags/KO_2.svg" alt="Korean" width="18" height="12"></a>

            <ul class="wpml-ls-sub-menu">
                
                    <li class="wpml-ls-slot-shortcode_actions wpml-ls-item wpml-ls-item-zh-hans">
                        <a href="https://www.myweb.com/?elementor_library=header" class="wpml-ls-link">
              <img class="wpml-ls-flag" src="https://www.myweb.com/wp-content/uploads/flags/CN_2.svg" alt="Japanese" width="18" height="12"></a>
                    </li>

                
                    <li class="wpml-ls-slot-shortcode_actions wpml-ls-item wpml-ls-item-en wpml-ls-last-item">
                        <a href="https://www.myweb.com/?elementor_library=header" class="wpml-ls-link">
                <img class="wpml-ls-flag" src="https://www.myweb.com/wp-content/uploads/flags/EN_2.svg" alt="English" width="18" height="12"></a>
                    </li>

                            </ul>

        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
</div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Codes I tried:

```
jQuery(".wpml-ls-legacy-dropdown").prop("disabled", true);
```

```
jQuery(".wpml-ls-legacy-dropdown").attr("disabled", true);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try : `jQuery(".wpml-ls-legacy-dropdown").css('pointer-events','none');`

Comment: Hi Swati: WoW, You are you are so so awesome! You always have the answer. I really admire you. Thank you a lot  Swati : )

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

`jQuery(".wpml-ls-legacy-dropdown").prop("readonly", "readonly");`

or

`jQuery(".wpml-ls-legacy-dropdown").prop("readonly", true);`

or try to .attr()

Comment: Hi Kuldeep Singh: Thank you for your help. I tried all the 4 codes, but they still dropdown. , I'm not sure if it's correct response but "readonly", true shows readonly="readonly" in html.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that the WPML language switcher? if yes there's a section in the setting where you can customize the language switcher appearance

[https://wpml.org/forums/topic/customize-the-language-switcher/#:~:text=Solution%3A%20In%20order%20to%20change,any%20part%20of%20your%20page](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/customize-the-language-switcher/#:%7E:text=Solution%3A%20In%20order%20to%20change,any%20part%20of%20your%20page).

Under WPML -> languages -> there's a section where you can customize (or add if it doesn't exist yet) your language selector

you can even preview how it will be display until it match your needs

Comment: Hi Diego: Thank you for your help. Yeah, it's WPML, and I need to disable the dropdown on a specific page.  So, I need the code and @Swati solved it. Thank you : )